# how to display user control inside a modal popup in windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have to display a usercontrol containing 2 datepickers, 2 buttons ( validate, cancel ) in a modal popup.
This popup is shown when the user has clicked on a specific button on the form.

Any ideas ?
Thnks in advance

Comment: @HighCore I think that what you're referring to is more about the developer themselves, and not the framework or methods they choose to use.  Tarring everyone who develops winforms with the same brush is not really fair.

Comment: @Adrian you're right. I deleted my previous comment. And Downvoted instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your user control to a `Form` -- say you called if `frmPopup`, create a new instance of it and call it with [ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx).  You need to have a pair of buttons on the `Form` as well to give the user a way to close or cancel the dialog.  Microsoft has more information for you [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55cz5x2c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
The example is in XAML but my project is in winform.

Comment: Oh, duh.  Sorry, I just woke up.  I'll grab the winforms example.

Comment: Resolved :

I've added a new control (PopupWindow1 ) that inherits from Window.

then put onto it the usercontrol

When the user click on the button , i've put :

PopupWindow1 p1 = new PopupWindow1();

p1.ShowDialog();

Comment: You have to handle the result from the dialog, remember.  And that means you also have to provide a result for the dialog.  The examples show you how.

Comment: Also, if this is your resolution please don't forget to mark the answer as correct.